# Runtime Configurable Angular Apps? Lets Share

Tags: angular, configuration, runtime

BLUF:
 How do you guys handle an automated deployment pipeline in angular?

Point:
 I have recently come up against a requirement to allow external configurations to be injected at runtime into angular applications. While I was able to figure it out, i'm not extremely confidant about the robustness or upgrade-ability of the methods I used. So i'm wondering if there is a preferred method of pulling in configs after compilation?

MY Method: *bare min version*
**app.module.ts**

```
export function injectServiceInit(service: ConfigService){
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return service.loadConfig();  
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  Imports: [...],
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: injectServiceInit,
      deps: [ConfigService],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
```

**config.service.ts**

```
import ...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService{
  private http: HttpClient;
  private appConfig: IAppConfig;

  constructor(private httpBackend: HttpBackend){
    this.http = new HttpClient(httpBackend);
  }

  loadConfig() {
    return this.http
      .get<IAppConfig>('assets/config.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then((data) => {
        this.appConfig = data;
      });
  };
  public getConfig() {
    return this.appConfig;
  }
}
```

With this method I can retrieve a json file from the projects asset folder on the server during runtime so we dont have to rebuild to reflect any changes. But this does require the program to wait for the config file to be loaded before it can execute and i had to change my **main.ts** file to not take into account the environment config because it occurs before bootstrapping so the config.json file hasnt been loaded yet.

Any cleaner implementations floating around out there?